# How aureliajs bind class attributes

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I can't understand why this not bind class, when i select box, selectedBox have index with number, i used function indexOf(index) > -1 to return true or false values.
Somebody can help me ?

```
<div class="col"  repeat.for="[item] of range(0, 25)">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" model.bind="item" checked.bind="selectedNumbers" class="d-none">
        <span class="boxList ${selectedNumbers.indexOf(item) ? 'active': ''}">${item | numberFormat}</span>
     </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to display 24 numbers, and add a `class` to the `span` when the checkbox is clicked:

I have created a [gist](https://gist.run/?id=a1c553146ab33666eadcab1b2b6ea1fb):

```
<div class="col" repeat.for="item of 25">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" model.bind="item" checked.bind="selected" class="d-none">
        <span class="boxList ${selected ? 'active': ''}">${item}</span>
    </label>
</div>
```